# Windows 7/WMP 12 is unable to sync with MTP device - Toshiba Gigabeat S30 (MES30V)

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, mtp

I have a Toshiba Gigabeat S30 (MES30V, same as MES60V) which operates as an [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) device.  I can plug the MP3 player in, and it appears to be detected correctly by Windows as an MTP player; however it does not show up in Windows Media Player.  I have downloaded Songbird, and it too detects the Gigabeat but Sonbird's MTP support is pretty weak.

Did Microsoft remove MTP support in Windows 7/Windows Media Player 12?  Is there anyway to get this working?

I should add that with Vista, the Gigabeat would show up as a drive in My Computer, that does not appear to be the case with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess I just solved this myself.  In device manager, I found the gigabeatS device under Portable Devices.  Right-Click and Uninstall removed device, and the Windows immediately detected it again and reinstalled the driver.  Afterwards, the device showed up correctly in WMP and My Computer.